# Are there any generic C++ APIs or SDKS for cameras that work on CE and Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-mobile, sdk, camera

I have a mobile application with versions run on TabletPCs (Win32) and Rugged PDAs (Windows CE, Windows Mobile 4 & 5).  Are there any SDKs out there that I can use that will work with a range of cameras across these operating systems?

On Windows CE I can use [SHCameraCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa454996.aspx) which will work with built in cameras, but typically not with externally connected cameras.  On Win32 there are vendor specific SDKs, such as [those offered by Canon](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=SDKHomePageAct&keycode=Sdk_Lic&fcategoryid=314&modelid=7474&id=3464), but not much generic other than FireWire based.

Has anyone come across any SDKs that abstract all of this into a simpler interface, or do I have to do this myself with various bits of hardware on an adhoc basis?  My requirement is to get a JPEG from the camera to the application on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is DirectShow but I wouldn't call it a simple interface.  That said when you get used to it its pretty easy and you won't be after much more functionality than [ICaptureGraphBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318240.aspx)

Comment: DirectShow usually unavailable for PDAs.

Comment: you may be right ... i've got it on mine ... but thats probably is the exception rather than the rule I assumed :(